# How to make user space code react to a kernel interrupt?

Tags: linux, kernel

If I write kernel code to handle interrupts, how can I inform user space code?
And how could user space code handle it? By a blocking `read()`?

Then the user space code can do nothing if the interrupt hasn't happened?
Or maybe a multi-threads user space code can be made: one thread is for the blocking `read()`, another thread can do things such as GUI update, etc, right?

Comment: Make your interrupt threaded (in kernel). In thread (bottom half) notify user-space using whatever mechanism you like. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673304/how-does-linux-kernel-interrupt-the-application/29673719#29673719) for details.